# How do I assign a queried data to a String or int in onBindViewHolder?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my class where I am querying Firestore (using the Firebase-UI for Cloud Firestore) and binding the data:

```
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MenuHolder holder, int position, @NonNull MenuItems model) {
        holder.textViewName.setText(model.getName());
        holder.textViewDescription.setText(model.getDescription());
```

This works if I am getting and setting values for a `TextView`. But if I just want to get the data and assign it to a string or parse it to an int, how would I do that?

Comment: What do you mean through "get the data and assign it to a string or parse it to an int"? Is any of your properties holding an int? As I see, both are strings.

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes both Name and Description are strings. Let's say there is a third variable i.e. TaxAmount that I need to do some calculations on but dont need to show in my recyclerview, how do I assign a variable to it? I dont have a textViewTax. Instead I have an int called valueTax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question and further comments, please see the code below:

```
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MenuHolder holder, int position, @NonNull MenuItems model) {
    String name = model.getName();
    holder.textViewName.setText(name);
    String description = model.getDescription();
    holder.textViewDescription.setText(description);
    int taxAmount = model.getTaxAmount();
    //Do what you need to do with it
}
```

See what I have done? Before setting the text to the actual text views, I have stored each value that is coming from a getters into a variable. I have done the same thing in case of the strings as well in the case of the integer. Obviously, I assumed that your `taxAmount` is of type `int`. If you want to diplay later in your project this property as well, please use the following line of code:

```
holder.textViewTaxAmount.setText(String.valueOf(taxAmount));
```